# Python SQLAlchemy pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Hi Everyone I  Am  working right now with Pandas and MSSQL.  I have bene working ok but recently after an SQlalchemy update i am getting the following error when I am trying to upload information into the DB via df.to_sql

pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

My connection is defined as follows

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://Reporter:******@localhost:1433/SourcingDb?driver=SQL+Server')
```

df.to_sql('ProductivityDeck', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index= False)

and the full error I get is this one

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/H212310/PycharmProjects/untitled2/UpdateCEDeckv2.py", line 23, in <module>
    df.to_sql('ProductivityDeck', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index= False)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2127, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 450, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1149, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 663, in insert
    self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 638, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(*self.insert_statement(data, conn))
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context  context)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
```

I have tried to rollback to  a lower version of SqlAlchemy, Update the ODBC driver in windows and upgrading the python installation and it keeps coming back.

Any ideas in how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please show contents of your dataframe and its `dtypes`.

Comment: I  could, but it got with any df of 1000+ rows, even one generated with rnd. Just went further and caught that it was a bug in Pandas, not in SqlAlchemy that is being worked out.

Thanks a lot for the interest!

Comment: did you ever work around this? having the same error and not getting anywhere!

Comment: It was pandas version, try to downgrade and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK this was a "silent error for a known bug in pandas 23, downgrading to v22 makes the error go away and  you can upload 1000+ rows.

this is being worked out on

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21103

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!').  The existing solutions on a few StackOverflow threads did not help.

In my case, the error came from `pyodbc.connect()`.

I ended up reinstalling python and dependencies and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

```py
pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};')
```

Just changing the driver worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

#### My Case

I wanted to supply my own experience with this error.

#### Context

- I'm using pyodbc and sqlalchemy on an Ubuntu machine in WSL on my Windows PC.
- I am connecting to a Progress OpenEdge database using the 'DataDirect 7.1 OpenEdge Wire Protocol' ODBC Driver.

From one day to the next I went from the connection test working fine, to getting the same "Driver did not supply an error!" message.

#### Troubleshooting

I tried everything I could think of including uninstall / reinstall of all dependencies. Changing my connection string, testing if that was causing the issue.

#### My Root Cause and Solution

What I found was the issue was that I was connecting to my organizations network via VPN. I went onsite and tested the connection and it worked. I can't explain why, but I can definitely single that out as the root cause.

---

Hope this helps spare someone hours of troubleshooting. Really unsatisfied with how vague of an error message pyodbc provides.